# How to use exclude_from in borg?

Tags: linux, borg-backup

According to [this page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/borgbackup/borg-patterns.1.en.html) it looks like the syntax of an exclude file should be

```
R /home/webserver/
- .dat1/
- .dat2
- .dat3*
- .dat4/Images\ System/*
- .compile/*/*/Cache
```

but all of these directories are still included.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re looking at the wrong example. The file you created is for `--patterns-from`, whereas a file for `--exclude-from` is just a list, like this:

```
*/.DS_Store
*/._*
*/node_modules
```

The example from the man page is this:

```
$ cat >exclude.txt <<EOF
# Comment line
/home/*/junk
*.tmp
fm:aa:something/*
re:^/home/[^/]\.tmp/
sh:/home/*/.thumbnails
EOF
```

It’s hidden in the long sequence of shell commands. This example includes other match types.